# Troubleshoot abnormal connections

Tags: oracle

We experienced extreme slowness of login on 6 Mar in 1 of our Oracle servers (Solaris 10) running Oracle DB. During that period of time, our firewall had detected and dropped many TCP connections (almost every min) that used port 48464, 64245, 64667 and 64996 to connect to another Oracle server (Solaris 10) that also running Oracle DB. No one knew what had happened.

We would like to find out the root cause of the problem if it happens again. Is there a way to trace these abnormal connections? Better still if there is any tools that can be activated once the problem surface since the incident can happen when the administrator is not around.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those ports aren't "standard" Oracle ports. Do you have the listener configured on those ports, or are you running other software on the boxes? There isn't really enough information to help you unless we know the full software stack.

Comment: My DBA had earlier declared that the ports were not from Oracle DB. From the firewall, the abnormal traffic will transmit from the source server at around 11 to 12 O'clock daily and the ports are random. 

Is there a way to track from source server?